# Monitoring docker with metricbeat inside docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers, monitoring, metricbeat

It's possible monitoring docker with metricbeat running in the docker containers?
it´s like monitoring docker from inside, with all elastic stack running in docker containers. it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use metricbeat inside docker as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html#_custom_image_configuration)